# Error: too few arguments to function 'strcmp'

Tags: c, string, input, count, strcmp

I am having a few issues with my code. First: when I try to compile, I get `error: too few arguments to function 'strcmp'`. I have looked all over and made multiple changes and am still unable to get it to work. Second: when my code does compile (if I remove the strcmp part), it will not complete the count functions correctly. Can anyone please assist? Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int count(char array[], int size);
int stringLen(char array[]);
int convert(char ch);
int value, n;

int main()
{
    //char * str;
    //char s;
    char a[100];
    char b[100];
    char c[100];
    int charCount = stringLen(a);
    int lCount = count(a, charCount);
    printf("Enter your string: \n");
    scanf("%s \n", a);
    printf("Enter your string: \n");
    scanf("%s \n", b);
    printf("Enter your string: \n");
    scanf("%s \n", c);
    printf("The count is %d, length is %d\n", lCount, charCount);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < charCount; i++)
    {
        char c = a[i];
        printf("Char %s = %d \n", &c, value);   
    }
    n = strcmp(char string1[], char string2[], char string3[]);
    printf("The first string in the alphabet is: %d \n", n);
    return 0;
}

int stringLen(char array[])
{ 
    char count;
    int index;
    while(array[index] !=0)
    {
       count++;
       index++;
    }
    return count;
}

int count(char array[], int size)
{
    int count;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] == 'a')
        {
            count ++;
        }
        else if(array[i] == 'A')
        {
            count ++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: `strcmp` takes two arguments, not three. Also, you are passing your parameters to the function incorrectly.  I know this is a C++ reference link but this should help you: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp

Comment: Would it be better to do this as a loop then? Make it look at A/B then A/C then B/C? (If that makes sense)

Comment: @iwant2flyaway: That *may* be the way. Or you could use an array and sort it. You'll also need to provide  and implementation for `stringLen()` (or use `strlen()` instead).

Comment: The issue is I have three arrays that will be taking user input and am I not sure the best way to handle strcmp() using C as I am still learning it.

Comment: Suggest removing the `" \n"` from `"%s \n"`.

Comment: Suggest `int index = 0;` in `stringLen()`.

Comment: Define `value` _someplace_ and change to `printf("Char %c = %d \n", c, value);`

Comment: Put `int charCount = stringLen(a); int lCount = count(a, charCount);` after `scanf("%s", a);`

Answer (score 0):

This is not right way to use strcmp.

> n = strcmp(char string1[], char string2[], char string3[]);

`strcmp` is used for compararison of string. See [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

```
int result = strcmp (string1,string2)
```

If strings are same, function will return 0.